Google Apps Script attempting to utilize OAuthScopes is giving an error with no details and prevents saving
The code
The error when saving
I'm very new to Apps Script, and I keep getting different errors with little to no details on what the error is. Most of the time, I'm able to figure them out, but I don't even have a clue where to start with this error. The documentation isn't much help, since it very specifically excludes all the context surrounding where I'm supposed to use OAuthScope. Google's documentation
I honestly don't even know what oauthScopes really does, I'm just trying to use the function getValue() on a specific cell, and I think that this is what I need to do so I can, but Apps Script refuses to make that easy.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code and error messages should be added as text, not as images.

The reason you are unable to save your manifest file is because you have a syntax error, you are missing a comma after the runtimeVersion value, here is a sample of the correct syntax:
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
}

The oauthScopes value is an important part of your manifest file as these scopes allow your script to access functions and data that requires authorization beyond the scopes that Apps Script automatically applies. For example the getvalues() function requires a scope in order to work[2].You can read more about Authorization Scopes in the following documentation.
[1] - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes
[2] - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

You really don't need to use OAuthScope to use getWidth(). You should review Apps Script Custom Functions on how to create a custom script. I'm not sure why the guide you are reading is editing a JSON file.
Here is a short script on how to use the getWidth function:
function myFunction() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get a range of cells, B2:E2
  var range = sheet.getRange('B2:E2');
  // Get the width of the range (4 columns)
  var width = range.getWidth();
  // Display a message with the width
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(width);
}


The reason (I think) I have to do this is because when using the function in the spreadsheet, it's giving me the error "TypeError: range.getWidth is not a function (line 22)." Just want to note, the issue is not that I did "range.getWidth", the actual code is "range.getWidth()", the error just omitted the ().

I just realized that I meant getValue() not getWidth() in the original post. I'm also having issues  with getWidth(), as stated in my last comment, but they are not related to OAuthScope. My bad.
